# saving data to firebase with angularfire2 - Ionic

Tags: object, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to upload an object to firebase, the problem is with storing the entire object in the database - only one of the properties is being stored, here it is:

```
constructor(af: AngularFireDatabase ...) {
    this.items = this.af.list('/appointments/' + this.username);
}

logForm() { //executed on a form submit
    this.items.push({day:{date:this.selectedDate, reserved:this.appointments}});
}
```

`this.items` is a `FirebaseListObservable` and everything works fine with that - when this push is successful, here is what is in the database:

[image]

As you can see, there is no `date` property in the database, only `reserved` (which is an `array` of `string`s), why isn't the date getting stored? I am new to `firebase`'s take on NoSQL - am I breaking a rule? Thanks.

Comment: We really need to see more than one line.

Comment: not really, the problem is more with firebase...all that matters is how i am storing the object, and how firebase is interpreting it....key part: `{day:{date:this.selectedDate, reserved:this.appointments}}`...the object that is being interpreted incorrectly...i think it has something to do with how you are supposed to structure firebase databases maybe..ill add more anyway

Comment: More is indeed needed. What are the values of `this.appointments` and `this.selectedDate`? You want to include enough here so that others can reproduce the problem. We can't do that without knowing what the input is. (hint: because I've seen these before, it's probably that `selectedDate` is null or not a parsable JSON value). See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i updated my code...see above...also i figured it out...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the object has to look like this:

```
{date:{day:this.selectedDate.toString()}, reserved:{appointment:this.appointments}}
```